# how to count multiple strings or one string at a time on a csv/text file and return the value including the string in tabulated data using powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

Below is the csv output converted from text file with comma "," delimeter:

```
           node       vserver   file-id connection-id session-id           open-mode share 
           ---------- --------- ------- ------------- -------------------- --------- ----- 
           node01 vserver101 91      396709148     15425954623650978960 r         Marketing
           node01 vserver101 96      396709148     15425954623650978960 rw        Marketing 
           node01 vserver101 109     396709149     15425954623650978960 rwd       Sales 
           node01 vserver101 110     396709149     15425954623650978960 r         Sales 
           node01 vserver101 119     396709149     15425954623650978960 rw        Sales 
           node01 vserver101 1       396710785     15425954623650979514 rw        HR 
           node01 vserver101 2       396710785     15425954623650979514 rwd       HR 
           node01 vserver101 19      396710785     15425954623650979514 r         HR 
           node01 vserver101 1       396714268     15425954623650980922 rw        Sales 
           node02 vserver102 437     1056740175    6208775036283845931  rw        Operations 
           node02 vserver102 669     1056740175    6208775036283845931  r         Operations 
           node02 vserver102 878     1056740175    6208775036283845931  rw        Operations 
           node02 vserver102 1435    1056740175    6208775036283845931  rw        Operations 
           node02 vserver102 1689    1056740175    6208775036283845931  r         Operations 
           14 entries were displayed.
```

My desired output is to count the number of Read (r) or Read/Write (rw) or Read/write/delete(rwd) per Share (e.g. Marketing/Sales/HR/Operation) and also per Vserver (e.g. vserver101/102) in tabulated format.

This is my desired output would be like this:

Share         r   rw  rwd
HR            1   1   1

Marketing     1   1   0

Sales         1   2   1

Operations    2   3   0

Vserver       r   rw   rwd

Vserver101    3   4    2

Vserver102    2   3    0

I need help. Please provide a sample script. Thanks a lot to all of you guys.

Yours truly,
Trying to code :)

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` then `Group-Object -Property share` for the first part, then `Group-Object -property vserver` for the second part.

Comment: Please provide sample script.

Comment: Please show us what deliniter character is used (**if** it is a CSV file) because now we can not see what the real structure is.. Open the file in notepad and copy/paste from there, or is this the actual content?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: From notepad:
node,vserver,file-id,connection-id,session-id,open-mode,share
node01,vserver101,91,396709148,15425954623650978960,r,Marketing
node01,vserver101,96,396709148,15425954623650978960,rw,Marketing
node01,vserver101,109,396709149,15425954623650978960,rwd,Sales
node01,vserver101,110,396709149,15425954623650978960,r,Sales
node01,vserver101,119,396709149,15425954623650978960,rw,Sales
node01,vserver101,1,396710785,15425954623650979514,rw,HR
node01,vserver101,2,396710785,15425954623650979514,rwd,HR
node01,vserver101,19,396710785,15425954623650979514,r,HR

Answer (score 1):

```
$csv = import-csv C:\ps\sample.csv
$csv| Group-Object share | Sort-Object Name | Select-Object Name, Count
```